# oracle rownum transfer to t-sql row_number() over with error

Tags: t-sql, plsql, rownum

the simplified origin pl_sql is

```
select t.*, staff_no||'-'||rownum as pk 
from (select * from hrmmgr.posting where type not in ('X','C') order by staff_no, postingdate) t;
```

I try to rewrite it to run in sql server as

```
select t.*, staff_no + '-' + t.rownum as pk
from (select row_number() over (order by staff_no, postingdate) as rownum, * 
from posting where type not in ('X','C') order by staff_no, postingdate) t
```

but error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
> tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
> or FOR XML is also specified.

is returned.

If I try to add OFFSET as shown in the error message as follow:

```
select t.*, staff_no + '-' + t.rownum as pk
from (select row_number() over (order by staff_no, postingdate OFFSET 0 ROWS) as rownum, * 
from posting where type not in ('X','C') order by staff_no, postingdate) t
```

then the following error is shown.

> Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

So how to rewrite my plsql to  run in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery appears to be the problem, and SQL Server is telling you that `ORDER BY` cannot appear in a subquery without also using something like `TOP`.  However, it should not even be necessary here, because your call to `ROW_NUMBER` already specifies an `ORDER BY` clause to be used when assigning row numbers.  Try this version:

```
SELECT t.*, staff_no + '-' + t.rownum AS pk
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY staff_no, postingdate) AS rownum, * 
    FROM posting
    WHERE type NOT IN ('X', 'C')
) t;
```

Comment: Oh, I misunderstand the order by error message is mean the order by in row_number() over.